# How to connect a phone battery with DC coreless motor?

Tags: batteries, motor, dc, dc-motor

I have this phone battery with 4 pins
[image]

And a [coreless DC Motor](https://pt.aliexpress.com/item/2set-716-7x16mm-Magnetic-Micro-Coreless-Motor-Propeller-DC-4-2V-55000RPM-coreless-aeromodelling-motor-high/1660122312.html?spm=2114.42010508.4.88.L4JrYo)

They work together(I've tried to attach them with my hands) however I don't know how to connect them and don't want to waste money on stuff I don't need.

If anyone could give a guideline it would be much appreciated.

Comment: The motor is rated at 4.2 V. It may rotate with 3.7 V still. But what is the purpose? What is the speed or torque you are expecting? Do you want to control the direction of rotation too?

Comment: 4.2V is the open-circuit voltage of a fully charged Li-ion/Lipo cell.  3.7V is the nominal voltage under load. All those '4.2V' coreless DC motors are actually designed to work with a 3.7V Lipo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have the phone it came from?  Is it scrap?   If so remove the battery holder.

The terminals are marked + and -, so it's just a matter of finding out if the black or the white wire on the motor is +.

If you do not have a battery holder, then tape wires to the terminals with electrical tape.